# n-way duel probability problem.

Tags: probability

Let's start with a simple problem:

> A and B enter a paintball duel, where each one has a 50% chance of tagging another. The game will last until there is one player left, who will become the winner. A goes first. Calculate the probability of A being the winner.

Let's call the probability of A being the winner is $x$.

When A goes first, A has a $1/2$ chance of tagging B, and the other $1/2$ B will has a $1/2$ chance of tagging A, and so on. Let's look at how symmetric this problem is: when A misses, B will play the game as if B goes first, in other word, B will take the role of A and have an $x$ chance of winning, which makes A has a $1-x$ chance of winning.

Therefore, we have the equation: $x = 1/2 + 1/2(1-x)\Leftrightarrow x=2/3$.

So the probability of A winning is $2/3$, B winning is $1/3$.

Another way to solve this problem is to think about the fact that when A and B both miss, which happens in $1/4$ of the time, where the game will return to its initial state, where A has an $x$ chance of winning,

We have another equation: $x = 1/2 + (1/4)(x)\Leftrightarrow x=2/3$.

Now, let's move on to the harder one:

> A, B and C enter a paintball duel, where each one has a 50% chance of tagging another. Each player will aim at the player of next turn.  The game will last until there is one player left, who will become the winner. A goes first, then B, then C. Calculate the probability of A being the winner.

This problem is harder because A does not automatically win when A tags B, because C will take the next turn and have a 50% chance of tagging A. But if we look carefully, we can see another pattern here, C will play against A where C goes first, which means this problem is reduced to a 2-way duel, where we already have the solution.

Let's call the probability of A being the winner is $x$.

A will have a $1/2$ chance of tagging B, and then C will go first against A, which means A only have $1/3$ chance of winning.

A will have a $1/2$ chance of not tagging B, then B will have a $1/2$ chance of tagging C and then A will go first against B, where A will win with $2/3$ chance; or B will have a $1/2$ chance of not tagging C and then C will have a $1/2$ chance of not tagging A, which makes the game return to its initial state, where A will have an $x$ chance of winning.

Therefore, we have the equation:

$x = (1/2)(1/3 + (1/2)(2/3 + (1/2)(x)))\Leftrightarrow x=8/21$

So the probability of A winning is $8/21$

B will have a 50% chance to take the role of A, only when A misses the first shot. So the probability of B winning is $4/21$

The probability of C winning will be $9/21 $

What's important to take note here is that C will not lose regardless of the result of A aiming at B and have the highest chance of winning despite going last.

I tried to use Python to simulate the n-ways duel, record the winner of a large number of matches (desirably 100000) and the only pattern I got from the results is the probability of the first player winning is double the probability of the second player winning, while I can't figure out the pattern of the remaining ones.

My questions are, how can I figure out the probability of each player winning in an n-way duel without calculating every single case. Is there a pattern or recursive manner hidden in this problem? Why does the denominator 21 exist in a 3-way duel?

Thanks for your time reading through all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there are $n$ players. As easy to understand the probability $r(n,k)$ that the $k$-th player will be tagged is:
$$
r(n,k)=\frac1{2^n-1}\times\begin{cases}
1,&k=1;\\
2^{n-k+1},&k\ne1.
\end{cases}\tag1
$$
After the $k$-th player leaves, we have the duel of $n-1$ players with shifted indices so that the $k+1$-th player becomes the first, and $k-1$-th player becomes the last $n-1$-th one.

Thus the probability that the $k$-th player survives all rounds can be recursively computed as ($1\le k\le n$):
$$
p(n,k)=\begin{cases}1,&n=1;\\
\sum\limits_{1\le i<k}r(n,i)p(n-1,k-i)+
\sum\limits_{k<i\le n}r(n,i)p(n-1,k-i+n),&n>1.
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

The solutions of the recurrence (2) are rational numbers $\frac{P_{nk}}{Q_n}$. The numerators $P_{nk}$ for small values $n$ and $k$ are given in the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{l|lrrrrr|r}
n&k\to&1&2&3&4&5&Q_n\\
\hline
1&&1&0&0&0&0&1\\
2&&2&1&0&0&0&3\\
3&&8&4&9&0&0&21\\
4&&104&52&86&73&0&315\\
5&&2272&1136&2180&1896&2281&9765
\end{array}
$$

The denominators (last column of the table) have the form:
$$
Q_n=\prod_{i=1}^n (2^i-1).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution although the second formula is quite overwhelming for me. By the way, I have a question, according to the result from the first formula, why do the chances of being tagged of player 1,2,3 in a 3-way duel are 1/7,4/7,2/7 respectively, but the chance of winning of player 3 is higher than player 1?

Comment: The second formula is a simple recurrence which can be easily programmed. The reason for the effect mentioned by you is the fact that in the 2-duel with the 1st the 3rd person will have 2 times more chance to win. In fact this was clarified already in your question. According to my calculations for $n>5$ the 1st person has the largest probability to win.